# Need help adapting script to multiple days of the week

Tags: google-sheets

I found this code in another post. For Google Sheets, basically it copies the color formatting in the "Status" tab and colors in the matching cells in "Monday".

```js
function colorCodeRevised() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var lr=ss.getSheetByName("Monday").getLastRow() // get last row of sheet1
  var lc=ss.getSheetByName("Monday").getLastColumn() //get last column of sheet1
  var lr1=ss.getSheetByName("Status").getLastRow() // get last row of sheet2
  var lc1=ss.getSheetByName("Status").getLastColumn() ////get last column of sheet2
  var sv=ss.getSheetByName("Monday").getRange(5,2,1,lc-15).getValues() // get vehicles. startrow,startcolumn,numrows to return,numcolumns to return
  var sn=ss.getSheetByName("Monday").getRange(6,1,lr-5,1).getValues() // get names
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Status").getRange(2,1,lr1-2,lc1)//exclude legend. squarebackets is sheet numbermm 0=1, 1=2
  var rng1=s1.getValues() // get sheet2 data
  var rng2=s1.getBackgrounds() // get background colors of dheet2 data

var test= sn.length
var test1= sv.length
var test2=rng1[0].length

var col=1 //column for vehicles on sheet1
   for(var m=0;m<sv[0].length;m++){ //for each vehicle
      col=col+1 //add one to vehicle column
  for(var n=0;n<sn.length;n++){ //for each name
  for(var i=0;i<rng1.length;i++){ //loop sheet2 data
  for(var j=0;j<rng1[0].length;j++){
  
    if(rng1[i][j].indexOf(sv[0][m])>-1 && rng1[i][j].indexOf(sn[n][0])>-1){ //if sheet2 data cell contains vehicle and name
       var c=ss.getSheetByName("Monday").getRange(n+6, col).setBackground(rng2[i][j]) //set color of vehicle and name on sheet1
  }}}}}
}
```

I have a very similar spreadsheet to this but I am struggling to make it run not only for Monday but for all the days of the week. I could make 6 identical scripts but I feel like it would be too taxing having the sheet run 7 scripts every time a change needs to be made. The cells that I want to be colored are in the exact same pattern/order as Monday. For example if C6 on Monday is red, C6 on Tuesday should also be red. Can anyone help me make this script color the same cells from Tuesday-Sunday as it does Monday, without it taking 7 times as long to run?

Comment: Can you give me a link to a spreadsheet with this code and some dummy data?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zQQ0n6Kiirs3MVOaVIBc6nzeLt_VT6ZHySF7HlBzPC8/edit?usp=sharing  @MichaelKenworthy here is a dummy sheet with all the days of the week. The script is in there too, as it is right now it will only color the monday sheet. But I am hoping to have it color all 7. It take a little while to run about 15s

Comment: I do plan on looking into this. Just haven't had a chance yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your specific question; I think all you really need to do is add a loop with a list of the sheets you want to modify. From there, you can just make everything a variable. That solution is shown last.

Before I just let you off with that though, I'd like to suggest a few changes ^_^

Getting that code-sample and making it work for your sheet was great! I liked the concept and I get where you are with organizing all of that data. I made some changes that (I think) might help you out.

Most of these changes were made with the intention of bringing the logic out of the script and into the sheet. The phenomenal thing about using the formulas in the sheets is that they are optimized by Google very well. If you could break down what you're looking to do into code-snippets that Google has implemented, things get much faster.

### Suggested changes:

1. Status page

   1. Changed to matrix of users and roles. Each role that someone plays has an x in it. In the future, you can populate this matrix based on a form input if that's what you're going for.
   2. Set A1 to contain all of the conditional formatting needed to properly color the table on the day pages.
   3. Manually colored the role headers since I didn't want to re-do all the conditional formatting in A1 and hierarchical conditional formatting isn't a thing.
2. Day pages

   1. Each cell in the color table now has a formula in it that will set the value to the role based on whether the user in that row has an x in that role on the status page.
   2. Based on the text in those cells, they are colored to have the class' selected color for the text and background.
3. The script

   1. Can be configured at the top with a list of pages to change and the location of the cell with the formatting.

      - I wish I could have created the formatting rules in the script, but that functionality isn't available yet. Hopefully it will be implemented when Google gets to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=162)
   2. Grabs the cell with the formatting
   3. Loops through each page
   4. Gets the color table
   5. Copies the formula (in the script) and the formatting to the table
   6. Finally, it adds a custom menu at the top that can be used to call the function named "Script tools".

### Advantages

- You only need to copy the formulas and formatting to each sheet once
- When changes are made in status, they are immediately reflected on the proper page

### Alternate solution

[link to my sheet](https://docs.google.com/a/kenworthy.io/spreadsheets/d/1T--2oeQyqVBawH_VnnMQaihHelj1ONqzltlRoTZvCD4/view)

[link to make an editable copy in your drive](https://docs.google.com/a/kenworthy.io/spreadsheets/d/1T--2oeQyqVBawH_VnnMQaihHelj1ONqzltlRoTZvCD4/copy)

```
/* Loops through all whitelisted sheets and applies a pre-defined format to the table on each.
 * 
 * Michael Kenworthy 12/21/16
*/

//Set-up variables
var whitelist = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
var colorKeySheet = "Status"
var colorKeyFormatCell = "A1"
var colorTableRange = "B6:M"

var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

function formatting() {
  statusSheet = doc.getSheetByName(colorKeySheet);
  formatCell = statusSheet.getRange(colorKeyFormatCell);

  for(var i=0; i<whitelist.length; i++){
    sheet = doc.getSheetByName(whitelist[i])
    colorTable = sheet.getRange(colorTableRange);

    cell = colorTable.getCell(1, 1)
    cell.setFormula('if(not(isblank(INDIRECT("Status!R"&MATCH($A6,Status!$A:$A,0)&"C"&MATCH(B$5,Status!$1:$1,0),false))),B$5,)')
    formatCell.copyTo(cell, {formatOnly: true});

    cell.copyTo(colorTable)
  }
}

function onLoad(){
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Sheet tools')
      .addItem('Apply formatting to day sheets', 'formatting')
      .addToUi();
}
```

### Solution to original question

```
var whitelist = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]

function colorCodeRevised() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()


  var lr1=ss.getSheetByName("Status").getLastRow() // get last row of sheet2
  var lc1=ss.getSheetByName("Status").getLastColumn() ////get last column of sheet2

  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Status").getRange(2,1,lr1-2,lc1)//exclude legend. squarebackets is sheet numbermm 0=1, 1=2
  var rng1=s1.getValues() // get sheet2 data
  var rng2=s1.getBackgrounds() // get background colors of dheet2 data

  for(var sheetNum=0;sheetNum<whitelist.length;sheetNum++){
    var lr=ss.getSheetByName(whiltelist[sheetNum]).getLastRow() // get last row of sheet1
    var lc=ss.getSheetByName(whiltelist[sheetNum]).getLastColumn() //get last column of sheet1
    var sv=ss.getSheetByName(whiltelist[sheetNum]).getRange(5,2,1,lc-15).getValues() // get vehicles. startrow,startcolumn,numrows to return,numcolumns to return
    var sn=ss.getSheetByName(whiltelist[sheetNum]).getRange(6,1,lr-5,1).getValues() // get names

    var col=1 //column for vehicles on sheet1
    for(var m=0;m<sv[0].length;m++){ //for each vehicle
      col=col+1 //add one to vehicle column
      for(var n=0;n<sn.length;n++){ //for each name
        for(var i=0;i<rng1.length;i++){ //loop sheet2 data
          for(var j=0;j<rng1[0].length;j++){
            if(rng1[i][j].indexOf(sv[0][m])>-1 && rng1[i][j].indexOf(sn[n][0])>-1){ //if sheet2 data cell contains vehicle and name
              var c=ss.getSheetByName(whiltelist[sheetNum]).getRange(n+6, col).setBackground(rng2[i][j]) //set color of vehicle and name on sheet1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it is exactly what I needed. I also appreciate the suggestions that you made to improve the sheet. Hmm is it possible to make the links in the "Alternate solution" to view only? When I try to ask for permission it gives me an error. There is also a little typo in the script I think

Comment: (sorry it wouldn't let me edit the above comment, I accidentally pressed enter) 
There is a little typo in the script above, I think you accidentally put "whiltelist" instead of "whitelist", but easily fixed".
Thanks again, and happy holidays ^_^

Comment: What do you mean links? To the spreadsheet or something else?

Comment: If you use the copy link and make a copy of the doc, you should be able to access the script. The reason I copied yours was because I couldn't see the script originally.

Comment: Yeah I was having trouble using the linked text "link to make an editable copy in your drive". As it was asking me to send you a request for permission. I thought the sheet was view only and that I could just File>make copy that way. I was just curious to see how the conditional formatting in A1 worked in the alternate solution.